# spring-integration-kafka Maven Build error: Can't find spring-integration-kafka:jar:1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I'm attempting to compile (with Maven) the simple kafka reference project I found here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka

However, I repeatedly get this error when I run mvn install -U

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project kafka: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.integration.samples:kafka:jar:4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in repo.spring.io.milestone (https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone) -> [Help 1]
```

When I go looking, I can see what appears to be the jar file in my .m2 folder - right where I think it ought to be -- under org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-kafka/1.2.2.BUILD.SNAPSHOT.  It does not end in .jar however, but rather .jar.lastUpdated

I tried loading the project into Spring Tools Suite as a maven project and attempted to clean the project... but in that case I get the error "Archive for Required Library...... in project 'kafka' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file.

I'm stumped - not sure where to go from here - I've blown away the directory and replaced it with the original project download several times.  Still no joy.

Oh, I also tried renaming the file in the hope it was a valid zip/jar, but apparently it isn't...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

========== Thanks Gary! ===========

I wiped the 'kafka' directory and re-added it from the zip I downloaded - then I tried adding that entry to the POM and got the following error:

```
ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'repositories.repository.id' must be unique: repo.spring.io.milestone -> https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone vs https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot @ line 114, column 8
```

I then changed the name of the repository so it would be different, thus:

```
<repository>
  <id>repo.spring.io.snapshot</id>
  <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

running mvn install -U again, I got the following warning and error about a problem with the POM for 1.3.0.M5 being missing...

```
[INFO] Building Apache Kafka Sample 4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.M5.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.M5 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.M5.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.922 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-29T11:28:18-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.M5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.M5 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

In case it helps (or in case of fat-fingering on my part) here's a copy of the POM...  Thanks again!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Apache Kafka Sample</name>
  <description>Apache Kafka Sample</description>
  <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration</url>
  <organization>
    <name>SpringIO</name>
    <url>https://spring.io</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>garyrussell</id>
      <name>Gary Russell</name>
      <email>grussell@pivotal.io</email>
      <roles>
        <role>project lead</role>
      </roles>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>markfisher</id>
      <name>Mark Fisher</name>
      <email>mfisher@pivotal.io</email>
      <roles>
        <role>project founder and lead emeritus</role>
      </roles>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>ghillert</id>
      <name>Gunnar Hillert</name>
      <email>ghillert@pivotal.io</email>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>abilan</id>
      <name>Artem Bilan</name>
      <email>abilan@pivotal.io</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples</url>
  </scm>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repo.spring.io.milestone</id>
      <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>repo.spring.io.snapshot</id>
      <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that attempting to use Maven to build this is a bad idea.  I keep getting deeper and deeper into errors.  I kinda figured that if there was a POM file, it should be a simple matter to 'mvn install' it...  Unless anyone has a flash of insight, I'm going to give up on the maven thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the POM; add

```
<repository>
  <id>repo.spring.io.snapshot</id>
  <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

to the repositories section.

Comment: To be honest, we don't build from the POMs (hence the bug), we generate the POMS from gradle. I just fixed the pom manually and it builds ok for me now; I also fixed a package name in the tests. If you pull the latest master you should be good to go. `mvn package` then `java -jar target/target/kafka-4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar`.